# Using apply to calculate mean squared error of two matrices

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to use apply to calculate the MSE of every row of two matrices, one of which is predictions and the other correct values.

My MSE function looks like

```
mse <- function(x_hat,x) {
    return(sum((x_hat-x)^2)/length(x))
}
```

And so the calculation of the first MSE would be of the form

```
mse(results[1,],real[1,])
```

How can I use apply to calculate this for every row of the two matrices? I am confused on what I would put in as the first parameter of apply since it has to be one variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could `lapply()` on the row indices, passing in `x_hat` and `x` as additional arguments. This would require a change to the MSE function, or a wrapper. I will show the both:

#### 1: rewrite mse() to take an row index as its first argument and use it

```
mse2 <- function(i, x_hat, x) {
  sum((x_hat[i,] - x[i,])^2) / length(x[i,])
}

lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), mse2, x_hat = x_hat, x = x)
```

#### 2: write a wrapper to `mse()`

```
wrap.mse <- function(i, x_hat, x) {
  mse(x_hat[i, ], x[i, ])
}

lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), wrap.mse, x_hat = x_hat, x = x)
```

The advantage of the wrapper is that `mse()` remains untouched and simpler than in the modified version.

You could change that `lapply()` calls to `sapply()` if you want the result simplifying to a vector of MSE values rather than a list.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `apply`. Your function is almost completely vectorized so that you can just put in your matrices and be done with it. This would work.

```
mse<-function(x_hat,x) rowMeans((x_hat-x)^2)
```

Now, you can just run:

```
mse(x_hat,x)
```

And you will get a vector of MSEs, one for each row.